# How to add new column conditional to NA in one column of data

Tags: r, mutate

I have been trying to make a new column in data set, lets say jk. I want in this column the values from column a6 if value in column a6b is NA, otherwise I need the value from column a6b. I have written the following line of code for this operation:

```
Combined_Data %>% mutate(jk=if_else(a6b!= NA , a6b, a6))
```

But instead if intended result, this code is converting all values in jk column to NAs.

What I have:

```
df
  a6 a6b
1 45  NA
2 62  32
3 NA  55
4 92 200
```

What I want:

```
df
  a6 a6b  jk
1 45  NA  45
2 62  32  32
3 NA  55  55
4 92 200 200
```

What I'm getting:

```
df
  a6 a6b  jk
1 45  NA  NA
2 62  32  NA
3 NA  55  NA
4 92 200  NA
```

Comment: can someone please edit my question and make tables neat. don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: We can't compare NA, try: `NA != NA` or `NA != 1`, so to check if it is NA, use `is.na(x)`. Also, useful function instead of if_else try [coalesce](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  mutate(jk = if_else(!is.na(a6b), a6b, a6))
```

Here I mostly follow your code. However, I recommend reversing the logic from negative to positive, thus:

```
df %>%
  mutate(jk = if_else(is.na(a6b), a6, a6b))
```

`NA`, understood as *missing values*, must be referred to with the **function** `is.na`. The format `a6b != "NA"` (with quote marks!) works if the value is the **string** `NA`, which are *not* missing values but strings. Since none of your observations in the two original columns are such strings, the `ifelse` command obviously, and correctly, returns `NA` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifelse` this way: condition, value if true, value if false:

```
jk = ifelse(is.na(a6b), a6, a6b)
```

Comment: but can you also explain what is wrong with my code. Since I'm also trying to say the same thing that if a6b is not NA take value of a6b otherwise a6